# merging data with matching sample name

Tags: r

I would like to add annotation info(anno) to the matching samples in the logtpm2 file.

for example, first picture here represents logtpm2 file (1,812,364 entries with expression data), and I would like to add 2 columns from the annotation data set (anno) which contains Treatment, and Technology columns. How do I match the logtpm2 data with the corresponding data sample? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]
[image]

The ideal data will have 1,812,364 rows with 3 columns in the end: Expression, Treatment, and technology

> data sample for logtpm2

```
      sample_name       Expression
1   bulk.DMSO.Pre.96IFC 0.05894781
2   bulk.TSA.Pre.96IFC  0.00000000
3   bulk.DMSO.Pre.800IFC    0.00000000
4   bulk.TSA.Pre.800IFC 0.00000000
5   bulk.DMSO.Post.800IFC   0.00000000
6   bulk.TSA.Post.800IFC    0.00000000
7   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046618_S78_L001    0.00000000
8   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046619_S79_L001    0.00000000
9   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046620_S80_L001    0.00000000
10  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046621_S81_L001    0.00000000
11  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046622_S82_L001    0.00000000
12  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046623_S83_L001    0.00000000
13  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046624_S84_L001    0.00000000
14  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046625_S85_L001    0.00000000
15  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046626_S86_L001    0.00000000
16  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046627_S87_L001    0.00000000
17  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046628_S88_L001    0.00000000
18  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046629_S89_L001    0.00000000
19  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046630_S90_L001    0.00000000
20  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046631_S91_L001    0.00000000
21  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046632_S92_L001    0.00000000
22  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046633_S93_L001    0.00000000
23  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046634_S94_L001    0.00000000
24  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046635_S95_L001    0.00000000
25  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046636_S96_L001    0.00000000
26  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046637_S97_L002    0.00000000
27  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046638_S98_L002    0.00000000
28  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046639_S99_L002    0.00000000
29  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046640_S100_L002   0.00000000
30  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046641_S101_L002   0.00000000
31  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046642_S102_L002   0.00000000
32  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046643_S103_L002   0.00000000
33  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046644_S104_L002   0.00000000
34  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046645_S105_L002   0.00000000
35  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046646_S106_L002   0.00000000
36  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046647_S107_L002   0.00000000
37  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046648_S108_L002   0.00000000
38  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046649_S109_L002   0.00000000
39  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046650_S110_L002   0.00000000
40  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046651_S111_L002   0.00000000
```

> data sample for annotation

```
        sample_name      Treatment      Technology     
    1   bulk.DMSO-Pre-96IFC DMSO    bulk
    2   bulk.TSA-Pre-96IFC  TSA bulk
    3   bulk.DMSO-Pre-800IFC    DMSO    bulk
    4   bulk.TSA-Pre-800IFC TSA bulk
    5   bulk.DMSO-Post-800IFC   DMSO    bulk
    6   bulk.TSA-Post-800IFC    TSA bulk
    7   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046618_S78_L001    TSA IFC96
    8   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046619_S79_L001    TSA IFC96
    9   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046620_S80_L001    TSA IFC96
    10  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046621_S81_L001    TSA IFC96
    11  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046622_S82_L001    TSA IFC96
    12  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046623_S83_L001    TSA IFC96
    13  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046624_S84_L001    TSA IFC96
    14  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046625_S85_L001    TSA IFC96
    15  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046626_S86_L001    TSA IFC96
    16  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046627_S87_L001    TSA IFC96
    17  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046628_S88_L001    TSA IFC96
    18  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046629_S89_L001    TSA IFC96
    19  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046630_S90_L001    TSA IFC96
    20  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046631_S91_L001    TSA IFC96
    21  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046632_S92_L001    TSA IFC96
    22  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046633_S93_L001    TSA IFC96
    23  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046634_S94_L001    TSA IFC96
    24  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046635_S95_L001    TSA IFC96
    25  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046636_S96_L001    TSA IFC96
    26  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046637_S97_L002    DMSO    IFC96
    27  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046638_S98_L002    DMSO    IFC96
    28  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046639_S99_L002    DMSO    IFC96
    29  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046640_S100_L002   DMSO    IFC96
    30  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046641_S101_L002   DMSO    IFC96
    31  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046642_S102_L002   DMSO    IFC96
    32  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046643_S103_L002   DMSO    IFC96
    33  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046644_S104_L002   DMSO    IFC96
    34  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046645_S105_L002   DMSO    IFC96
    35  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046646_S106_L002   DMSO    IFC96
    36  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046647_S107_L002   DMSO    IFC96
    37  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046648_S108_L002   DMSO    IFC96
    38  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046649_S109_L002   DMSO    IFC96
    39  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046650_S110_L002   DMSO    IFC96
    40  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046651_S111_L002   DMSO    IFC96
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share a small sample dataset using `dput`? For example, you can use `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: sure! I"ll update it soon! @neuron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert row names in the second dataframe to column called `names`, removing row names after it:

```
logtpm2$names <- rownames(logtpm2)
logtpm2 <- data.frame(logtpm2, row.names=NULL)
```

Then simply `left_join` the first dataframe with the second:

```
logtpm1 %>% left_join(logtpm2, by = "names")
```

**Edit:**

`logtpm2` dataframe:

```
logtpm2 <- read.table(text = "sample_name   Expression
bulk.DMSO.Pre.96IFC 0.05894781
bulk.TSA.Pre.96IFC  0
bulk.DMSO.Pre.800IFC    0
bulk.TSA.Pre.800IFC 0
bulk.DMSO.Post.800IFC   0
bulk.TSA.Post.800IFC    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046618_S78_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046619_S79_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046620_S80_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046621_S81_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046622_S82_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046623_S83_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046624_S84_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046625_S85_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046626_S86_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046627_S87_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046628_S88_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046629_S89_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046630_S90_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046631_S91_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046632_S92_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046633_S93_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046634_S94_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046635_S95_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046636_S96_L001    0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046637_S97_L002    0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046638_S98_L002    0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046639_S99_L002    0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046640_S100_L002   0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046641_S101_L002   0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046642_S102_L002   0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046643_S103_L002   0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046644_S104_L002   0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046645_S105_L002   0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046646_S106_L002   0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046647_S107_L002   0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046648_S108_L002   0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046649_S109_L002   0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046650_S110_L002   0
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046651_S111_L002   0
", header = TRUE)
```

`logtpm1` dataframe:

```
logtpm1 <- read.table(text = "sample_name   Treatment   Technology
bulk.DMSO-Pre-96IFC DMSO    bulk
bulk.TSA-Pre-96IFC  TSA bulk
bulk.DMSO-Pre-800IFC    DMSO    bulk
bulk.TSA-Pre-800IFC TSA bulk
bulk.DMSO-Post-800IFC   DMSO    bulk
bulk.TSA-Post-800IFC    TSA bulk
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046618_S78_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046619_S79_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046620_S80_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046621_S81_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046622_S82_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046623_S83_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046624_S84_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046625_S85_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046626_S86_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046627_S87_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046628_S88_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046629_S89_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046630_S90_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046631_S91_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046632_S92_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046633_S93_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046634_S94_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046635_S95_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046636_S96_L001    TSA IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046637_S97_L002    DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046638_S98_L002    DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046639_S99_L002    DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046640_S100_L002   DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046641_S101_L002   DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046642_S102_L002   DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046643_S103_L002   DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046644_S104_L002   DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046645_S105_L002   DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046646_S106_L002   DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046647_S107_L002   DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046648_S108_L002   DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046649_S109_L002   DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046650_S110_L002   DMSO    IFC96
ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046651_S111_L002   DMSO    IFC96
", header = TRUE)
```

This command:

```
logtpm2 %>% left_join(logtpm1, by = "sample_name")
```

Returns this:

```
                             sample_name Expression Treatment Technology
1                    bulk.DMSO.Pre.96IFC 0.05894781      <NA>       <NA>
2                     bulk.TSA.Pre.96IFC 0.00000000      <NA>       <NA>
3                   bulk.DMSO.Pre.800IFC 0.00000000      <NA>       <NA>
4                    bulk.TSA.Pre.800IFC 0.00000000      <NA>       <NA>
5                  bulk.DMSO.Post.800IFC 0.00000000      <NA>       <NA>
6                   bulk.TSA.Post.800IFC 0.00000000      <NA>       <NA>
7   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046618_S78_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
8   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046619_S79_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
9   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046620_S80_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
10  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046621_S81_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
11  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046622_S82_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
12  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046623_S83_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
13  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046624_S84_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
14  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046625_S85_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
15  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046626_S86_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
16  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046627_S87_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
17  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046628_S88_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
18  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046629_S89_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
19  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046630_S90_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
20  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046631_S91_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
21  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046632_S92_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
22  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046633_S93_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
23  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046634_S94_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
24  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046635_S95_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
25  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046636_S96_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
26  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046637_S97_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
27  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046638_S98_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
28  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046639_S99_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
29 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046640_S100_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
30 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046641_S101_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
31 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046642_S102_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
32 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046643_S103_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
33 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046644_S104_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
34 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046645_S105_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
35 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046646_S106_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
36 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046647_S107_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
37 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046648_S108_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
38 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046649_S109_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
39 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046650_S110_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
40 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046651_S111_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
```

Cases where `Treatment` or `Technology` is `NA` are the ones where there's no matching `sample_name` in `logtpm1`.

**Edit 2:**

As you have noticed, there are slight differences in `sample_name` spellings in the two datasets. Let's find which ones are not matching.

These `sample_names` are not found in `logtpm2`:

```
logtpm2$sample_name[!logtpm2$sample_name %in% logtpm1$sample_name]

[1] "bulk.DMSO.Pre.96IFC"   "bulk.TSA.Pre.96IFC"    "bulk.DMSO.Pre.800IFC"  "bulk.TSA.Pre.800IFC"   "bulk.DMSO.Post.800IFC" "bulk.TSA.Post.800IFC"
```

And these are not found in `logtpm1`:

```
logtpm1$sample_name[!logtpm1$sample_name %in% logtpm2$sample_name]

[1] "bulk.DMSO-Pre-96IFC"   "bulk.TSA-Pre-96IFC"    "bulk.DMSO-Pre-800IFC"  "bulk.TSA-Pre-800IFC"   "bulk.DMSO-Post-800IFC" "bulk.TSA-Post-800IFC"
```

Assuming you don't really care about dashes and dots, we can simply substitute all dashes with dots in `sample_names` of both datasets:

```
logtpm2$sample_name <- gsub('-', '.', logtpm2$sample_name)
logtpm1$sample_name <- gsub('-', '.', logtpm1$sample_name)
```

Now the same command:

```
library(dplyr)
logtpm2 %>% left_join(logtpm1, by = "sample_name")
```

will result in:

```
                             sample_name Expression Treatment Technology
1                    bulk.DMSO.Pre.96IFC 0.05894781      DMSO       bulk
2                     bulk.TSA.Pre.96IFC 0.00000000       TSA       bulk
3                   bulk.DMSO.Pre.800IFC 0.00000000      DMSO       bulk
4                    bulk.TSA.Pre.800IFC 0.00000000       TSA       bulk
5                  bulk.DMSO.Post.800IFC 0.00000000      DMSO       bulk
6                   bulk.TSA.Post.800IFC 0.00000000       TSA       bulk
7   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046618_S78_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
8   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046619_S79_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
9   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046620_S80_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
10  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046621_S81_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
11  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046622_S82_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
12  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046623_S83_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
13  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046624_S84_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
14  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046625_S85_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
15  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046626_S86_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
16  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046627_S87_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
17  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046628_S88_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
18  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046629_S89_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
19  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046630_S90_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
20  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046631_S91_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
21  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046632_S92_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
22  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046633_S93_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
23  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046634_S94_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
24  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046635_S95_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
25  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046636_S96_L001 0.00000000       TSA      IFC96
26  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046637_S97_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
27  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046638_S98_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
28  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046639_S99_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
29 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046640_S100_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
30 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046641_S101_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
31 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046642_S102_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
32 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046643_S103_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
33 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046644_S104_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
34 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046645_S105_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
35 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046646_S106_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
36 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046647_S107_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
37 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046648_S108_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
38 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046649_S109_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
39 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046650_S110_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
40 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046651_S111_L002 0.00000000      DMSO      IFC96
```

A full match as you can see. However, this is just a sample. Investigate all the names that are not matching in the two datasets (as I have shown before) and see what is the best way to perform substitutions of characters in `sample_names` of both dataframes to eliminate mismatching names.

Comment: Uff, don't have a lot of experience tackling memory limitations. I suggest including this as the main point of your question now, since joining the two dataframes otherwise is quite simple.

Comment: Thanks for your kind input! I managed to make some datasets in the end. But also, there is pretty lots of NA values in the Treatment and Technology somehow when there shouldn't.

Comment: Seems like `names` columns are not matching in those cases (spelling?), or maybe a single instance of `names` from the first dataframe occurs multiple times in the second one. Try taking a name that has NAs in the other columns and filter both dataframes by it to investigate. And it would of course be best if you shared a reproducible example - a smaller portion of your data to test.

Comment: I shared! thanks!

Comment: The samples that you shared do not have column names. Also I noticed that `Technology` column represents different data in the two screenshots

Comment: Yes, I got the same answer. But if we really think about it, bulk.DMSO.Pre.96IFC has the actual value of Treatment = DMSO, and Technology = bulk. simply we can see it with our eyes. and that's why it's odd.

Comment: oh. there's '.' and '-' difference! Will there be any way to just ignore this slight difference?

Comment: Yep. Edited my answer. Substituting `-` with `.`  in `sample_names` of both dataframes should be enough for this sample. But as I mention in my answer, if your real data has more mismatching names, this is a data cleaning exercise of it's own and you should investigate what characters it's best to substitute to make names in both dataframes identical. Hope this helps! (I also recommend checking `full_join`, `inner_join`, `right_join` so that you can be sure you are joining the two datasets correctly according to your needs)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
annotation %<>% 
  select(-Technology) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("Technology")

pattern <- paste0(unique(annotation$Treatment), collapse = "|")

logtpm2 %>% 
  left_join(annotation, by = "Technology") %>% 
  mutate(Treatment = ifelse(str_detect(Technology, pattern), 
                            str_remove(str_sub(Technology, 6L, 9L),"\\."), 
                            Treatment))
```

output:

```
     Technology Expression Treatment
1                    bulk.DMSO.Pre.96IFC 0.05894781      DMSO
2                     bulk.TSA.Pre.96IFC 0.00000000       TSA
3                   bulk.DMSO.Pre.800IFC 0.00000000      DMSO
4                    bulk.TSA.Pre.800IFC 0.00000000       TSA
5                  bulk.DMSO.Post.800IFC 0.00000000      DMSO
6                   bulk.TSA.Post.800IFC 0.00000000       TSA
7   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046618_S78_L001 0.00000000       TSA
8   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046619_S79_L001 0.00000000       TSA
9   ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046620_S80_L001 0.00000000       TSA
10  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046621_S81_L001 0.00000000       TSA
11  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046622_S82_L001 0.00000000       TSA
12  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046623_S83_L001 0.00000000       TSA
13  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046624_S84_L001 0.00000000       TSA
14  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046625_S85_L001 0.00000000       TSA
15  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046626_S86_L001 0.00000000       TSA
16  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046627_S87_L001 0.00000000       TSA
17  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046628_S88_L001 0.00000000       TSA
18  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046629_S89_L001 0.00000000       TSA
19  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046630_S90_L001 0.00000000       TSA
20  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046631_S91_L001 0.00000000       TSA
21  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046632_S92_L001 0.00000000       TSA
22  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046633_S93_L001 0.00000000       TSA
23  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046634_S94_L001 0.00000000       TSA
24  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046635_S95_L001 0.00000000       TSA
25  ifc96.LIB018588_GEN00046636_S96_L001 0.00000000       TSA
26  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046637_S97_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
27  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046638_S98_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
28  ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046639_S99_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
29 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046640_S100_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
30 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046641_S101_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
31 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046642_S102_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
32 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046643_S103_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
33 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046644_S104_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
34 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046645_S105_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
35 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046646_S106_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
36 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046647_S107_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
37 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046648_S108_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
38 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046649_S109_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
39 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046650_S110_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
40 ifc96.LIB018589_GEN00046651_S111_L002 0.00000000      DMSO
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you!!